# Understanding child_process module and exec functionality when using it to execute a file

Tags: node.js, child-process

I new to node.js and trying to understand the syntax and exactly what is happening line by line in my code. This code runs a file hello.js with one argument arg1 and takes some time to execute. The file console logs out the current command it is working on every few seconds. I would like to know:

1) how to stop the file from running (abort in case of a problem);

2) how to pass the current command, that the file is console logging out, back to the client side;

3) what the ', child;' part of the syntax and '.on(' part of they syntax does. Thanks a bunch.

This code is running on the server side initiated by a jQuery POST from the client side. The client side sends a param to the server side and the server passes that param as an argument into a file and runs it. While the file is running, it is using console.log to output information every few seconds.

I want to pass that info back to the jQuery post in real time so each command can be had in real time on the client side. I also don't under stand the '.on('data', )' part of the code. Does .on mean 'on completion' or 'onwards do this' and also I don't under stand the '.exec, child;' part of the syntax.

````
var myExecute = require('child_process').exec, child;

var shellScript = myExecute('node hello.js arg1'); //run a file with an argument

shellScript.stdout.on('data', (data)=>{
      console.log(data);//file output console logs appearing here in real time                
});
shellScript.stderr.on('data', (data)=>{ 
      console.error(data);
});```

I am not getting any error messages. Currently the file is running and accepting the argument param passed in. I want to be able to abort this process from the client side once it had begun and I want to get back the data that the file is console logging and pass it back to the client side jQuery POST in real time.
````

Comment: Can you add the definition of `myExecute` to the problem? There are multiple ways of executing commands in node, and it would be helpful to know which you are using

Answer (score 0):

> > 1) how to stop the file from running (abort in case of a problem);

To stop a child process you use the function kill(), in your case it would be something like this: `shellScript.kill();`

> > 2) how to pass the current command, that the file is console logging out, back to the client side;

You do not provide much context in this regard but you should use the callback for `stdout` (read example below)

> > 3) what the ', child;' part of the syntax and '.on(' part of they syntax does.

The `child`  in your example is just a variable and, if I have to guess, it is there just because the code has been copy pasted. If I'd had to guess again, I'll say that `child` was intended to be used as a reference to the child process, but you went for `shellScript` instead. Have in mind that it is not a good practices to declare variables in the same place an import is made, it confuses people!

The `.on` part is a way to subscribe to events, in this case you are subscribing to the standard output and standard error of the child process. This means that anytime the process writes something to stdout/stderr, this function will be called (this is not entirely accurate, data is buffered).

And here is a copy of your code with some comments, hopefully it will make more sense now.

```
// import child_process API
var myExecute = require('child_process').exec;

// I think this is a proper use of child
var child = myExecute('node hello.js arg1');

// do something anytime there's data to read
child.stdout.on('data', (data)=>{
    console.log('STDOUT from child process: ', data);

    // TODO: Send data back to client side
});

// do something when the process writes to stderr
// Note: console.log() writes to stdout, console.error() writes to stderr
child.stderr.on('data', (data)=>{ 
    console.error('error detected: ', data);
    // kill child process
    child.kill();

    // TODO: Send error data to client
});
```

As a personal note, I rather import just `child_process` and then cal `child_process.exec`, just in case I need another function later. Like this:

```
var child_process = require('child_proces');

var child = child_process.exec(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and pass callback so that when there is *data* event just pass it to the callback. *stdout*[poor choice of name though] in this case a callback.

```
const executeCommand = (cmd, finish, stdout) => {
      console.log(`cmd : ${cmd}`);

      let proc = child.exec(cmd);
      proc.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        if (stdout)
          stdout(data);
      });
      proc.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(`stderr - ${data}`);
        proc.kill();
      });
      proc.on('close', function(code) {
         finish(code);
      });
    }
```

You can call that method now.

```
let command = 'ls -la'; // sample
executeCommand(command, function(code) {
         // this one is invoked when *close* event is emitted from child process
        //code === 0 meaning it ran fine.
        if(code === 255) {
          // meaning SSH connection was not successful
          return reject(new Error('Error in establishing SSH connection'));
        }
        return resolve(`message`);
      }, function(data) {
          // you get back the data here
          // can check for certain value
      });
```

I'm not entirely sure if you can send the data to JQuery post method, as it would be running on separate process, but you can use socket to broadcast to a room or emit that data to a particular socket client.